# Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithURL' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableURLRequest, (_, _, _) throws -> _)'

Tags: json, swift, http, request

```
//Send user data to server
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/signUp")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "name =\(userName)&email=\(userEmail)&password=\(userPassword) "
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)


    // task execution & JSON
```

Error

> Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithURL' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableURLRequest, (_, _, _) throws -> _)'

[image]

But I want to invoke dataTaskWithUrl with this argument how can I do:

```
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(request){
        data, response, error in

        if (error != nil){
            print("error\(error)")
            return
        }

        var err:NSError?

        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

        if let parseJson = json{
            var resultValue = parseJson["status"] as? String
            print("result\(resultValue)")


            var isUserRegistred:Bool = false
            if (resultValue == "Succes"){
                isUserRegistred = true
            }

            var messageToDisplay:String = parseJson["message"] as String!
            if (!isUserRegistred){
                messageToDisplay = parseJson["message"] as String!
            }

            //Launch asynchrone (different thread)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                //Display confirmation message
                let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message:messageToDisplay, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

                let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default){ action in
                    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
                }
                myAlert.addAction(okAction)
                self.presentViewController(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            })
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: `dataTaskWithURL`, as its name states, needs an URL, but you're giving it a request. Use `dataTaskWithRequest` instead for your request. Or use `dataTaskWithURL` with an URL. Well, you got the idea.

Comment: Thanks you for this response but even if dataTaskWithRequest i have the issus that tell me : Cannot invoke 'dataTaskWithRequest' with an argument list of type '(NSMutableURLRequest, (_, _, _) throws -> _)'
i think i have to convert my var request to an URLrequest or something because request is a NSMutableUrlRequest

Comment: I can't reproduce this error. Showing a screenshot of your error message in Xcode for better inspection of the issue may be helpful. (use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35522419/edit) button under your question)

Comment: i can't embed an image because i'm new and i need 10 reputation points 
can i send it it via email ?

Comment: No email please. ;) But you can paste a link to the image in your question instead of embedding the image. I'll click on the link and if needed I'll embed the image myself in your question.

Comment: i've added the link you just have to add ":" after file to see it. Thanks :)

Comment: This is a link to a local file on your computer, we can't use it. :/ First put the file on imgur.com, dropbox or something like it to get a valid link.

Comment: now it's ok i'm sorry for this and thank you for your answers

Comment: No problem. Edit done.

Comment: do you have an idea where the error come from ?

Comment: The problem is a missing bracket after NSJSON serialization

Comment: You need also to implement do try catch error handling after that line

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand how i have to implements this